# Timeline Preview does not work on Kdenlive 19

Tags: ubuntu, video-editing, kdenlive

After upgrading to Kdenlive 19 (19.04.0), the timeline preview stopped working. It stops after a few seconds with the first segment changing from red to orange and then back to red. If I start Kdenlive on the terminal, I get this error when I start the preview render:

```
Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
```

It was working fine on Kdenlive 18. My system is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: It seems to work again on version 19.04.2!